# Definition of the set $\mathbb{Z}_+$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, foundations

I'm currently going through the introductory chapters of Munkres' *Topology*, and in chapter 1 section 4 of the second edition, Munkres attempts to briefly establish some Mathematical foundations for the study of Topology. In particular, he assumes a set of axioms for $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. the so-called Field axioms), and from them he is able to obtain the set $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers. He does so as follows:

A subset $A$ of real numbers is **inductive**  if it contains the number $1$ (whose existence is given by one of the field axioms) and if for every $x \in A$, $x+1$ is also in $A$.

Then, letting $\mathcal{A}$ be the collection of all inductive subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, he defines $\mathbb{Z}_+$ as:
$$ \mathbb{Z}_+ = \bigcap_{A \in \mathcal{A}} A$$

Intuitively this makes sense since if $A$ is inductive, $1$ is necessarily in $A$ (by definition) and so is $1+1 = 2$ and $2+1 = 3$ and so on.

However, for a novice such as myself, this begs the question, why didn't we just define $\mathbb{Z}_+$ as $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$ in the first place (indeed, many texts introducing elementary set theory do just this). What am I missing here?

Comment: The set of all real numbers is inductive since it satisfies the definition. You could think of various subsets of the reals, each of which is inductive. The intersection of all inductive sets is the smallest inductive set, and this is $\Bbb Z_+$. This sets contains only the elements that every inductive set necessarily contains, namely $1$, and $x+1$ for each $x$. Some more inductive sets: All rationals, or all positive rationals, or all positive reals, or all number of the form $\frac n2$ where $n$ runs through the integers.

Comment: I'm sorry I guess I should clarify - I don't have an issue with why $\mathbb{Z}_+$, as Munkres defines it, will give us the set $\{1,2, \ldots \}$. My issue is more along the lines of, why is this roundabout, indirect construction necessary?

Comment: Because it may not be clear what the dots mean in $\{1,2,...\}$

Comment: Saying $\Bbb Z_+$ is $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ is not a definition. Saying $\Bbb Z+$ is a model of the Peano axioms is a definition.

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you so much that makes a bit more sense

Comment: To me, it is not clear if the roundabout approach is necessary, in particular if it brings a better understanding of the positive integers than what you already "know" by $\{1,2,\ldots \}$. (It does bring axiomatization). Munkres "cheats" and takes the reals for granted. In set theory one usually first defines the natural numbers (including $0$) as the smallest inductive set, where a set $I$ is inductive if: (a) the empty set $\emptyset\in I$, and (b) if $x\in I$ then $x\cup\{x\}\in I$. The axiom of infinity says there is an inductive set. Some mathematicians reject the existence of infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Volume 2 of Ewald's "From Kant to Hilbert" you can find a paper on formalism written by Hilbert. He is very clear that constructive accounts of mathematics are deprecated in formalism. Things like Dedekind cuts and Cauchy sequences are representable in formalist real numbers. They just do not have any significance in the sense of logical or constructive priority.

If you read Munkres with this in mind, there is no "cheating" and it is perfectly understandable. He introduces the real numbers as those objects being discussed. He associates the membership relation with extensions obtained by comprehension of properties.  And, he applies this account of how he is using logic to the domain of objects under discussion -- the reals as given under his fomalist axiomatization.

To obtain the positive integers, he defines a class of classes -- the class of classes satisfying his account of an inductive class. He then quantifies over this class in order to take the intersection yielding the positive integers.

So, this is like  "third-order" operation, or something like that.

The hint that makes this somewhat apparent is in the exercises. In one exercise he points out that it is not possible to generate Russell's paradox with the approach he has taken.

My copy of Munkres is pretty old (1975?). But I would bet that particular exercise can be found in later editions.